# AEM servlet not render in publisher instance

Tags: ajax, templates, components, aem, publish

I have followed this [tutorial](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/using/custom-sling-servlets.html) to create a form to submit data to SlingAllMethodsServlet .  It works fine with the author instance. Once I published the page It shows the blank page in publisher instance.

[image]

[image]

I have installed the AEM 6.2 in ubuntu 14.04 machine. To create the above form I have used the templates & components. This is the error logs print when render the publisher instance.

```
10.06.2020 23:00:55.463 *INFO* [sling-default-1297-com.day.cq.replication.impl.ReverseReplicator.2114] com.day.cq.replication.Agent.publish_reverse sent. Response: 200 OK
10.06.2020 23:00:55.463 *INFO* [sling-default-1297-com.day.cq.replication.impl.ReverseReplicator.2114] com.day.cq.replication.Agent.publish_reverse ------------------------------------------------
10.06.2020 23:00:55.463 *INFO* [sling-default-1297-com.day.cq.replication.impl.ReverseReplicator.2114] com.day.cq.replication.Agent.publish_reverse Sending message to localhost:4503
10.06.2020 23:00:55.463 *INFO* [sling-default-1297-com.day.cq.replication.impl.ReverseReplicator.2114] com.day.cq.replication.Agent.publish_reverse >> GET /bin/receive?sling:authRequestLogin=1 HTTP/1.0
10.06.2020 23:00:55.463 *INFO* [sling-default-1297-com.day.cq.replication.impl.ReverseReplicator.2114] com.day.cq.replication.Agent.publish_reverse >> Action: Internal Poll
10.06.2020 23:00:55.463 *INFO* [sling-default-1297-com.day.cq.replication.impl.ReverseReplicator.2114] com.day.cq.replication.Agent.publish_reverse >> Path: 
10.06.2020 23:00:55.463 *INFO* [sling-default-1297-com.day.cq.replication.impl.ReverseReplicator.2114] com.day.cq.replication.Agent.publish_reverse >> Handle: 
10.06.2020 23:00:55.463 *INFO* [sling-default-1297-com.day.cq.replication.impl.ReverseReplicator.2114] com.day.cq.replication.Agent.publish_reverse --
10.06.2020 23:00:55.463 *INFO* [sling-default-1297-com.day.cq.replication.impl.ReverseReplicator.2114] com.day.cq.replication.Agent.publish_reverse << HTTP/1.1 200 OK
10.06.2020 23:00:55.463 *INFO* [sling-default-1297-com.day.cq.replication.impl.ReverseReplicator.2114] com.day.cq.replication.Agent.publish_reverse << Date: Wed, 10 Jun 2020 17:30:55 GMT
10.06.2020 23:00:55.463 *INFO* [sling-default-1297-com.day.cq.replication.impl.ReverseReplicator.2114] com.day.cq.replication.Agent.publish_reverse << X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
10.06.2020 23:00:55.463 *INFO* [sling-default-1297-com.day.cq.replication.impl.ReverseReplicator.2114] com.day.cq.replication.Agent.publish_reverse << Content-Type: application/octet-stream
10.06.2020 23:00:55.463 *INFO* [sling-default-1297-com.day.cq.replication.impl.ReverseReplicator.2114] com.day.cq.replication.Agent.publish_reverse << Content-Length: 32
10.06.2020 23:00:55.463 *INFO* [sling-default-1297-com.day.cq.replication.impl.ReverseReplicator.2114] com.day.cq.replication.Agent.publish_reverse Message sent.
10.06.2020 23:00:55.463 *INFO* [sling-default-1297-com.day.cq.replication.impl.ReverseReplicator.2114] com.day.cq.replication.Agent.publish_reverse ------------------------------------------------
10.06.2020 23:00:55.463 *INFO* [sling-default-1297-com.day.cq.replication.impl.ReverseReplicator.2114] com.day.cq.replication.Agent.publish_reverse Reverse replication successful.
10.06.2020 23:00:55.463 *INFO* [sling-default-1297-com.day.cq.replication.impl.ReverseReplicator.2114] com.day.cq.replication.Agent.publish_reverse Fetched 0 contents from http://localhost:4503/bin/receive?sling:authRequestLogin=1 since null
```

Comment: The reverse replication should not be related to your error. You can safely disable the replication agent. Also, AEM 6.2 is already deprecated. The first thing you should check on your publish instance is that actually all code is deployed there, to me it seems that the page is replicated but the underlying code (/apps/<your-project-code>) is missing. Can you check the OSGi bundle is available in the publish instance?

Comment: These logs are indeed not relevant to your problem, try and add some logs to your servlet to know whether it is called or not, you can also check the sling recent requests to track what is rendering the page and whether or not all components are found.

Answer (score -1):

So actually you expect us to read the referenced tutorial to find out what the expected result is here and then we should do some magic to guess what went wrong in your case and help you while you sit there and wait? Really? I mean, REALLY?

Let me tell you about a big AEM secret: There is a mysterious thing called "The allknowing error.log". Maybe you should have a look first and if you are worthy, it might tell you what the problem is...

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I got the error log when I render the page in publisher instance . But the problem is it is not specifically menation the issue that is why I didn't put in question . For your reference I have updated the question. Thanks for help